# How can convert Maple formula to Mathtype format

Tags: editor, formula, maple, mathml

as you know when working with Maple each equation you typed with maple format will be seen like as mathtype after calculation with default blue font, for example you type QK:=Matrix(3,3,[Q[1,1],Q[1,2],0,Q[2,1],Q[2,2],0,0,0,Q[3,3]]); and you see this in the matrix format with subscript of each member of matrix. If you want to send this output to MS word software you got the picture of equation that can not edited or formatted like as mathtype formulation.
the question is how can I convert Maple output calculation to mathtype format?
I have found MathML formulation editor but when copy maple output on it, it can  show formulation only in the plain text format that can not calculate or convert to the mathtype format.

Comment: MathType is a 3rd party product that can use OLE to embed equations into MS-Office. You can use Maple commands like `MathML:-Export` or `MathML:-ExportContent` or `MathML:-ExportPresentation` to convert a Maple Matrix or expression into MathML (as a string), which Mathtype purports to support for import. Is that the kind of thing you tried? A Matrix is rendered as marked-up "2D Math" in Maple, but it is not "mathtype" inside Maple (which you seem to be suggesting).

Comment: I want to export every output in the maple to mathtype not just matrix.
the output maybe have Greek character,Mathematical operator and ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, find it!
at the first step right click on Maple output and select special copy and select copy as MathMl and paste it on the Formulator editor. at the second step copy the available formula in the Formulator and paste it on the Mathtype. the result was excellent for formula that dont have any Greek character, but if Greek character is available in the output formula, the result in the Formulator substitute this character with english spell with & sign at first and ; sing at the end. I want to find solution for this problem as example β change to &betta;

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have discovered the answer that we (Design Science) have on our website: http://www.dessci.com/en/support/mathtype/works_with.asp#!target=maple. One issue with Maple's MathML when pasted into MathType is the attributes it adds to the markup. For example, this is the MathML output from Maple for the variable *x*:

```
<mi mathcolor='#0000ff' color='#0000ff' fontstyle='2D Output' fontweight='normal'>x</mi>
```

Those 4 attributes help to replicate the look of the math as displayed in Maple, but they're unnecessary in MathType and most anywhere else you may paste the MathML. It doesn't take long before all these attributes contribute so much overhead that MathType simply can't handle it. (MathType thinks it's taking so long to interpret the MathML that surely it's in an infinite loop -- and gives an error.)

The problem with the Greek letters from Maple is that what should be a single character ampersand – & – comes out in the MathML markup as the entity for ampersand: **`&amp;`**. It would be great if MathType could just look at that and think "Hmm. Ok, I'm pretty sure Maple meant just **&**, so I'll assume that." But it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

Let M be maple form. For finding latex form you can use this commend:
`latex(M)`